# Adsense: You have rejected ad requests, which will result in lost revenue

Tags: google-adsense

Got an alert on my adsense account which says

> You have rejected ad requests, which will result in lost revenue. The following ad units have made ad requests with incorrect site information. This occurs when the URL of the server from which the ad unit has been served differs from the URL of the actual page where the ad will be displayed. [Learn how to fix these errors.](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_&utm_source=aso&answer=2594855)

So the solution is that I'll have to use "google_page_url = "http://myurl.com/fullpath";"

I'm using wordpress, what should be the URL for google_page_url? For example my website is [www.technostall.com](http://www.technostall.com). Should I put www.technostall.com there or should I give the path of each post? That is not good because I'm using a sidebar widget for sidebar ad unit. I can't change google_page_url for each page. What should I do?

This error is appearing only on my sidebar/navigation ad units.

Is using google_page_url = document.location; fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change your AdSense ad code because of this rejected ad requests issue! This is a system glitch that Google will correct.

Google has recognized and added the issue to their “Known Issues” list with the following description:

> ### Some accounts incorrectly notified about rejected ad requests
>
> We
> recently changed the way our system surfaces alerts related to
> rejected ad requests. This has resulted in some publishers seeing an
> alert in their AdSense accounts about needing to fix rejected ad
> requests, though no action is required on their part.
>
> We’re quickly working to fix this so that only publishers who need to
> take action will see the alert. We hope to have this resolved in the
> next couple of days, and we’ll update the known issues page when the
> update is live. If you are concerned about this alert, please check
> your account after that, and if you still see the notice, follow the
> instructions in the Help Center to resolve the issue. Note that the
> vast majority (over 90%) of publishers now seeing this notification
> will not see it after the fix. If the instructions in the Help Center
> don’t seem to apply to you, you are probably one of the publishers who
> should not be seeing this alert notification.
>
> Thank you for your patience as we resolve this issue with our
> notification system.

Source: [Google Support](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1067521)